# How to make a Java constructor for a class that implements an interface

Tags: java, oop

I have an interface I need to use that looks similar to:

```
public interface Classroom {
    enum Grade {
        Primary, Elementary
    }

    Map<String, String> students();

    String grade();

    Optional<String> teacher();
}
```

I know in order to use an interface, I need to implement it as a class. However, I don't understand how to create the constructor for the class? I don't have any other methods or variables to add to the interface Classroom, I just need a constructor for it so I can use it and create a Classroom object.

```
public class BiologyClassroom implements Classroom {
    public BiologyClassroom(Map<String, String> students, String grade, Optional<String> teacher) {
        // not sure what to put here?
    }
}
```

When I do try to use the interface by doing `Classroom classroom = new Classroom()` which I know is wrong, my IDE will fix it by by replacing it with:

```
Classroom classroom = new Classroom() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> students() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Grade grade() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<String> teacher() {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
```

I don't know how to interpret this suggestion from my IDE, am I supposed to write methods for `students()`, `grade()` etc? I just need to make a Classroom object using my own values for students, grade and teacher.

I am new to Java.

Comment: You need to create fields, assign them from constructor args, and return each in its own method.

Comment: The fact that it implements an interface has nothing to do with how to write a constructor.

Comment: `this.students = students;`

Comment: why would it be any different from a class that doesn't implement a constructor?

Comment: Your IDE is creating an anonymous class that implements the `Classroom` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods in your interface are actually getters (that don't start with "get"), so if you want to avoid repeating too much code, you can use an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClassroom implements Classroom {
    private final Map<String, String> students;
    private final Grade grade;
    private final Optional<String> teacher;

    protected AbstractClassroom(Map<String, String> students, Grade grade, Optional<String> teacher) {
        this.students = students;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> students() {
        return students;
    }

    @Override
    public Grade grade() {
        return grade;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<String> teacher() {
        return teacher;
    }
}
```

You can then write your class `BiologyClassroom` as follows:

```
public class BiologyClassroom extends AbstractClassroom {
    public BiologyClassroom(Map<String, String> students, String grade, Optional<String> teacher) {
        super(students, grade, teacher);
    }
}
```

You can also consider dropping the interface and use the abstract class instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your *interface* you have declared *students*, *grades*, and *teacher* as methods.
I believe you are intending to use them as *variables*.

Just use basic inheritance; there is no need for an *interface*, per se.

```java
class Classroom {
    enum Grade {
        Primary, Elementary
    }

    Map<String, String> students;
    String grade;
    Optional<String> teacher;

    public Classroom(Map<String, String> students, String grade, Optional<String> teacher) {
        this.students = students;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
}
```

```java
class BiologyClassroom extends Classroom {
    public BiologyClassroom(Map<String, String> students, String grade, Optional<String> teacher) {
        super(students, grade, teacher);
    }
}
```

Here is the *Java* tutorial on inheritance.
*[Inheritance (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)*.

Comment: The interface was not made by me so I can't change it